# EF Core 6 code first one to zero or one navigation

Tags: entity-framework-core, navigation, one-to-zero-or-one

I have googled as well as searched SO for this extensively, to no avail.

```cs
    class Account 
    {
    [Key]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string AccountID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
    public virtual Address? Address { get; set; }
    }

    class Address
    {
    [Key]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string AccountID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    }
```

Address should be optional - if it's not there, the application should still work.

The migration builder seems to have the relationship between the tables inverted:

```cs
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Account",
        columns: table => new
        {
            AccountID = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(80)", maxLength: 80, nullable: false),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", nullable: true),
            Email = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", nullable: true),
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Account", x => x.AccountID);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Account_Address_AccountID",
                column: x => x.AccountID,
                principalTable: "Address",
                principalColumn: "AccountID");
        });
```

Now when I try to insert data in the Account table, I am getting an error message about a conflict with a foreign key restraint in the Address table. It looks like there must already be a record in the Address table with the account id I am using to insert data in the Account table.

How do I fix this?

Hint: My fluent API does not offer .Optional() or .WithOptional().

Comment: `public virtual Address { get; set; }` is not valid C#

Comment: I wish you had offered useful advice instead of nitpicking on an error in some sample code (which I have btw. fixed, saw it myself).

Comment: I believe this is getting tripped up because you are declaring the FK attribute in Account's Address to use AccountId which is non-nullable. (As it should be as the PK, but this ends up treating Address as the principal side of relationship) If instead you declare an Account on Address and set it's FK to Account ID I suspect that mapping would work.  It should be possible to use a shadow navigation property if you don't want an Account reference from Address. In any case something to try to narrow down the problem.